# How can I access the content of a Chrome extension from outside the browser - e.g. I'd the content to be use in a script I'm writing?

Tags: python, shell, unix, google-chrome-extension

Assume I'm using a Chrome extension that gives me a nice summary of content on a webpage. Rather than writing my own program to mimic the services of the extension, I'd like to create a script that then uses the summary information that the extension generates, capturing it in a variable that I can manipulate.

Is this possible to write a script that could achieve this? If so, what would be good a starting point? I'd like to write the script in perhaps unix or python.

Comment: Ive never really done python or unix stuff but Ive seen simple servers done in python, did a google and got this... http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php .. use that and then send stuff to it from the extension with XMLHttpRequest and react to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will have to locate where it stores the summary information you want. Is it in RAM temporarily or is it persistant across reboots and the sort? What kind of information? If the information is stored temporarily, like per session, it could make what you wish to accomplish a little more difficult. If the summary data is stored locally this could be achieved a bit easier. For instance if it was stored locally, you could write some python to open the file that would contain your summary information, read it into a variable and then parse that information into whatever format you need it in.

Pretty open ended question though, can you offer any more details?